# How to get dropdown menus to align with the correct menu tab

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to get my CSS drop down menu to align with the item that is being hovered over. For some reason, it always is at one corner. The relevant CSS & HTML codes are here http://jsfiddle.net/AnQwL/1/

I've tried looking at examples to see if I'm doing something different, but I couldn't find a mistake. The positioning to the far left is because I've set `position: absolute`. However, without this, everything goes awry. Also, all the other examples use absolute positioning too.

Also, how do I get it to be horizontal? i.e., in a line instead of one below the other?

I'd appreciate any help in solving this. There is a possible duplicate here [css dropdown menu appears at the first tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703158/css-dropdown-menu-appears-at-the-first-tab) however, the question wasn't answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to relatively position the outer `<li>`s. Using `position: absolute` positions the element absolutely relative to the closest `relative`ly `position`ed element.

http://jsfiddle.net/Eric/MkKWa/

Also, you misused the `id` in the original: you had two `#submenu` elements, which is incorrect usage of the `id` attribute.

Comment: wait... so there should be only one `id` of each in the entire document? I thought I had closed that `ul` and the next one was different... Should I be using `.submenu` instead?

Comment: Thanks, I just checked your code and that's what you've done. Thanks for sorting that out!!

Comment: Correct. There should be only one of each id in the entire document, allowing it to be used as a url hash. Generally, you should use classes, unless you can guarantee that the element is unique.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a horizontal menu you need the ul li elements floating left. And to make the submenu to open at the right place you need to specify position relative for ul li and position absolute for ul li Ul.

Try it ;)